# For loop confusion in c program

Tags: c, for-loop

Why the loop is running from 2 to 7?

```
int i;    
for(i=1;i<=6;printf("\n%d\n",i))    
i++;
```

The output of this is

> ```
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> ```

but limit of `i` is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the for loop in an unusual manner.

The operation of a for loop is given below.

1. The initialization is done first. `i=1`
2. Then the expression is checked `i<=6`
3. Then the body is carried out `i++`
4. Then the increment is carried out. In your case this is `printf("\n%d\n",i)`
5. Repeat Step 2 to 4, until step 2 is FALSE.

In your case, you can see that the `printf` will be done for `i==7` first, and then the expression will be checked for `i==7`. After that the for loop will exit. Similarly the first print will be done only after one increment on `i`

So, first print will be for `2` and last will be for `7`

Comment: `You have written the for loop in a non standard manner.`...how so? What is non-standard in this?

Comment: `printf("\n%d\n",i)` is not an increment. I realize you are attempting to refer to the expression that is in the third position of the for-loop, which is quite often an increment. But you ought to use a better term for it.

Comment: Generally the increment is the last expression. In his case, the increment is in the body.

Comment: I have updated the term to unusual rather than non-standard to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Exactly sir, that is unconventional, awkward and likely to be avoided (I'd do that meself), but there's nothing "non-standard" about it, regarding the compliance.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't necessarily disagree (as indicated earlier), but it's better with the clarification (which we have now, thanks to you).

Answer (score 8):

The Syntax of a `for` loop is

> `for (` *clause-1* `;` *expression-2* `;` *expression-3* `)` *statement*

The execution is as below, quoting from `C11`, chapter §6.8.5.3, (*emphasis mine*)

> The expression `expression-2` is the controlling expression that is
>   evaluated **before each execution of the loop body**. The expression `expression-3` is
>   evaluated as a void expression **after each execution of the loop body.** [....]

Here, `i++` is the body and `printf("\n%d\n",i)` is the *expression-3*.

So, the order of execution would be something like

```
 i = 1;
 start loop

    i < = 6          //==> TRUE
    i++;            //i == 2
    printf         // Will print 2    ///iteration 1  done

    i < = 6         //==> TRUE
    i++;           //i == 3
    printf        // Will print 3   ///iteration 2  done
    .
    .
    .
    i < = 6         //==> TRUE
    i++;           //i == 6
    printf        // Will print 6   ///iteration 5  done

    i < = 6         //==> TRUE
    i++;           //i == 7
    printf        // Will print 7   ///iteration 6  done

    i < = 6 ==> FALSE

 end loop.
```

Comment: All three correct answers have one vote down each. I think that is as much data as we need about the motivation.

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop like

```
for(i=1;i<=6;printf("\n%d\n",i))    
    i++;
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    i = 1;  // Initialization clause from for loop

    while (i <= 6)    // Condition clause from for loop
    {
        i++;  // Body of for loop

        printf("\n%d\n", i);  // "Increment" clause from for loop
    }

}
```

As you can see, the `printf` is done *after* the variable `i` is incremented, which of course means it will print the incremented value (`2` to `7`).

Comment: All three correct answers have one vote down each. I think that is as much data as we need about the motivation.

Answer (score 2):

The workings of the loop are equivalent to the now-obvious

```
int i;    
for (i = 1; i <= 6; /*intentionally blank*/){
    i++;
    printf("\n%d\n", i);
}
```

as, conceptually, the 3rd expression in the `for` loop is ran just before the closing brace of the loop body.

Answer (score -5):

You've written the loop incorrectly - you've swapped the body of the loop with the incrementation code. So after having done `i++` which is in the body of the loop, it does the `printf` as the incrementation when that should be the other way around.

Write the `for` loop correctly as follows.

```
int i;    
for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
    printf("\n%d\n",i)
```

Comment: There is no basis for your statement “You've written the loop incorrectly.” We do not know that OP wrote it at all. It is not incorrect according to the C standard. We do not know what the intent of its author was; it might have been written specifically to demonstrate the flexible semantics of `for` loops in C. If so, it was written correctly for that purpose. Additionally, your answer does not explain the operation of the loop, so it does not answer the question “Why the loop is running from 2 to 7?”

Comment: The purpose according to the OP is that it is meant to count from 1 to 6 - so on that basis it's written incorrectly. If they wanted it to count from 2 to 7 it would be correct, if a little unconventional

Comment: The question contains no statement of purpose of the code.